# fusiontable infowindow style on googlemaps api

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a map with googlemaps api.

I've added a polygon FusionTable layer.

When I click on a polygon, it shows me the default infowindow with .googft-info-window class.

I want to make changes to that class, or assign other class to these infowindows.

There's a way to do so?

That's my code.

```
function initialize() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('lugar-do-mapa');
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.726084,-51.855469),
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          navigationControl: true,
          navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
          }
});
fusion = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: 'xxxxXXXxxx'
    },
    styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
      fillOpacity: 0.1,
      strokeColor: "#ff4d4d",
    strokeWeight: "int"
    }
    }]
  });
  fusion.setMap(map);
}
```

Thank you all,

Comment: http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171216

Comment: I think that I've already answered my own question. It works like Dr.Molle said, just placed the class .googft-info-window on my css and changed the parameters...thanks.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, but I can't find a way to prize Dr.Molle for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like [Dr. Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle) said, just placed the class **.googft-info-window** on my css and changed the parameters...thanks.